# why fresh-tabula-js not working with nestJs?

Tags: nestjs, tabula

**Getting errors while using fresh-tabula-js with nestJs.**

**Express server**

```
import Tabula from "fresh-tabula-js";

const table = new Tabula("t5.pdf", { spreadsheet: true });
  console.log(table.extractCsv().output);
```

**NestJS**

**1) code-1**

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import Tabula = require('fresh-tabula-js');

@Injectable()
export class PdfExtractorService {
  tabula: Tabula;
  constructor() {
    this.tabula = new Tabula('t5.pdf', { spreadsheet: true });
  }

  extractPdfToJson() {
    const data: Promise<{ output: string; error: string }> =
      this.tabula.getData();
    console.log(data);
  }
}
```

**Error:**
this.tabula.getData is not a function

**2) code-2**

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import Tabula = require('fresh-tabula-js');

@Injectable()
export class PdfExtractorService {
  tabula: Tabula;
  constructor() {
    this.tabula = new Tabula('t5.pdf', { spreadsheet: true });
  }

  extractPdfToJson() {
    const data: Promise<{ output: string; error: string }> =
      this.tabula.extractCsv().output;
    console.log(data);
  }
}
```

**Error:**
error TS2339: Property 'extractCsv' does not exist on type 'Tabula'.
this.tabula.extractCsv().output;

*Tried all possible ways but it is not working with nestJs however it is working with expressJs.*
How to make it run in nestJS?